# Xamarin.forms Translate App in more languages

Tags: xamarin.forms, multilingual

Hello guys i'm making a xamarin.forms app. When user register he need to choose language from the list of languages(in my case 4 languages), but i don't know how to organize depending of user's decision button's headers,menus etc. must be translated. Any idea how to make this?

Comment: This is called "Localization" - typically you do this automatically based on the user's device settings.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/localization

Comment: You might want to look at the open source project GitTrends which does this. https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends

Comment: I know about localization. I want to create like dictionaries in web. Generate Dictionary for languages i want to have in the app. And dynamically what user choose i get that dictionary

Comment: @GeraldVersluis i need if user choose english load English Resource file , if choose spanish i need to load spanish resource file

Comment: That's what that app allows you to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with [Multilingual App Toolkit to add Languages to Your Xamarin Apps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/add-languages-to-your-apps-with-xamarin-and-multilingual-app-toolkit/) .

Traditionally, after ensuring the localization is wired up and displaying correctly, you would finish adding all the app’s resource data before considering adding additional languages to avoid managing the changes to the resource or the related translation during the ongoing development process.

It’s best to validate that your app’s language support is working correctly throughout the development process to avoid bugs that may delay your app’s release, or worse, cause you to reduce market support by cutting additional language support.

This is where the [Multilingual App Toolkit (MAT](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308)) comes in.It can manage your target **REXS** files by applying on-demand Machine Translations throughout the development process. Once development nears completion, you can have the translations proofed and adjusted by family, friends, co-workers, or translation vendors.